# exported variable not persisted after script execution

Tags: bash, solaris

I'm facing a wierd issue.
I've a vm with solaris 11, and trying to write some bash scripts.

if, on the shell, I type :

```
export TEST=aaa
```

and subsequently run:

```
set
```

I correctly see a new environment variable named TEST whose value is aaa.
If, however I do basically the same thing in a script. when the script terminates, I do not see the variable set.
To make a concrete example, if in a file test.sh I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo 1: $TEST   #variable not defined yet, expect to print only 1:
echo 2: $USER
TEST=sss
echo 3:  $TEST
export TEST
echo 4:  $TEST
```

it prints:

```
1:
2: daniele
3: sss
4: sss
```

and after its execution, TEST is not set in the shell.
Am I missing something?
I tried both to do export TEST=sss and the separate variable set/export with no difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

export - make variable available for child processes, but not for parent.

source - run script in shell without creating child process

For exalmpe, persistent variable can be realised by writing to file

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo 1: $TEST   #variable not defined yet, expect to print only 1:
CONFIGFILE=~/test-persistent.vars
if [ -r ${CONFIGFILE} ]; then
  # Read the configfile if it's existing and readable
  source ${CONFIGFILE}
fi
echo 2: $TEST
echo 3: $USER
TEST=sss
echo 4:  $TEST
echo TEST="$TEST"> ${CONFIGFILE}
echo 5:  $TEST
```

Comment: This is also not exactly what I wanted to achieve, but I got your point. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To make your variables visible, you need to `source` the script which exports your variables. See `man source`.

Comment: likely there isn't a source manpage, and you want `help source` in bash instead.

Comment: this works if I directly invoke the script, (i.e. if I source the script with the export from the shell), but it doesn't seem to work if I source the script from within another script.